# Get data from API and seperate it into variables with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to request data and then populate 9 different `P` tags with the relevant attributes only I'm struggling with how to do it.

```
// Gets BTC Price in 3 currencies
var btc = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR,GBP";

// Gets ETH Price in 3 currencies
var eth = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR,GBP";

// Gets LTC Price in 3 currencies
var ltc = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=LTC&tsyms=USD,EUR,GBP";

$.getJSON( btc, function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( key + val );
  });

  // see fetched data to then be stored for later use...
  alert( "JSON Data: " + items[1,1] );

});
```

I've not worked with API's before so I'm unsure if ill need to have 3 `getJSON` functions too or if I can somehow combine these?

Here's a fiddle showing my progress so far

https://jsfiddle.net/mvs26pv8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can insert the values with [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
// Gets BTC Price in 3 currencies
getData('btc', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,EUR,GBP');

// Gets ETH Price in 3 currencies
getData('eth', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD,EUR,GBP');

// Gets LTC Price in 3 currencies
getData('ltc', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=LTC&tsyms=USD,EUR,GBP');

function getData(prefix, url) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('.' + prefix + '-' + key.toLowerCase()).html(val);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>BTC in EUR = <span class="btc-eur"></span></p>
<p>BTC in GBP = <span class="btc-gbp"></span></p>
<p>BTC in USD = <span class="btc-usd"></span></p>

<br/><br/>

<p>ETH in EUR = <span class="eth-eur"></span></p>
<p>ETH in GBP = <span class="eth-gbp"></span></p>
<p>ETH in USD = <span class="eth-usd"></span></p>

<br/><br/>

<p>LTC in EUR = <span class="ltc-eur"></span></p>
<p>LTC in GBP = <span class="ltc-gbp"></span></p>
<p>LTC in USD = <span class="ltc-usd"></span></p>
```