# How to set interval for get data from API (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, json, setinterval

I have a simple question: I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686183/get-data-from-api-and-seperate-it-into-variables-with-jquery) function for getting prices from CryptoCompare and now I would like set interval for refreshing data without refreshing page. So I have tried this code:

```
<script>
    getData('dash', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=DASH&tsyms=USD');
    
    function getData(prefix, url) {
      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          $('.' + prefix + '-' + key.toLowerCase()).html(val);
        });
      });
    }
    setInterval(getData, 3000);
    $(function() {
      getData();
    });
</script>
```

But it is not working for me. Can you help me, please?

Edit:
Used on website [https://investplus.cz/](https://investplus.cz/investice/seznam-kryptomen-kurzy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some convoluted code. I think what you are intending is for your fetch to be called every 3 seconds.

```
function getData(prefix, url) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('.' + prefix + '-' + key.toLowerCase()).html(val);
    });
  });
}
```

This defines you get function. You have a sample call as

```
getData('dash', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=DASH&tsyms=USD');
```

You are using setInterval incorrectly though, see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

You have 2 lines here

```
setInterval(getData, 3000);
$(function() {            getData();        });
```

This is incorrect, getData is only a name for your function. The setInterval function should take your anonymous function with defined parameters like

```
setInterval($(function() {           
  getData('dash', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=DASH&tsyms=USD'); 
}), 3000);
```

Per your JS fiddle, this works for me (removed jquery function and replaced with regular js lambda)

```
function getData(prefix, url) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('.' + prefix + '-' + key.toLowerCase()).html(val);
    });
  });
}
setInterval(function() {    
  getData('btc', 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD'); 
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answear @zakk . I appreciate it. As you wrote, I would like to fetch data from Cryptocompare every 3 seconds without refreshing page. I tried put the last code from your answear instead of 2 incorrect lines. However, the script fetch the data only once.

Comment: I tested it in Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/uyc6doeh/ . There is still some mistake ...